# Fortran error : The shapes of the array expressions do not conform

Tags: arrays, size, fortran

I am facing an error in a program . To show the error, I have added this little program and the associated error. I would rally appreciate some help.

```
PROGRAM TRY
      IMPLICIT NONE
      REAL(KIND=8) :: A(6,6),B(6,6)
      INTEGER :: I, J
      REAL(KIND=8) :: RHO, H
      REAL(KIND=8) :: C(5,2),D(2,5),E(5,5)
!
      RHO=780
      H=0.5D0
      DO I=1,6
         DO J=1,6
             A(I,J)=1
         ENDDO
      ENDDO 

      B=RHO*H**2.0D0*A
      DO I=1,5
         DO J=1,2
             C(I,J)=I+J
         ENDDO    
      ENDDO

      OPEN(1,FILE='OUTPUT.DAT')
      DO I=1,6
          WRITE(1,20) (B(I,J), J=1,6)
      ENDDO
      DO I=1,5
         DO J=1,2
              D(J,I)=C(I,J)
         ENDDO
      ENDDO
      E=C*D
      DO I=1,5
          WRITE(1,20) (E(I,J), J=1,5)
      ENDDO
      CLOSE(1)

20    FORMAT (999(2x,EN14.4))     

      END PROGRAM TRY
```

I get the following error message:

```
fortran_worksheet.f(32): error #6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform.
      E=C*D
---------^
fortran_worksheet.f(32): error #6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform.   [E]
      E=C*D
------^
compilation aborted for fortran_worksheet.f (code 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to multiply a `5 x 2` matrix with a `2 x 5` matrix in an element-wise fashion. This is bound to fail!

For a matrix-matrix multiplication you should use e.g. the [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) routine [`DGEMM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Matrix_Multiply). See [here](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/tutorials/mkl_mmx_f/GUID-36BFBCE9-EB0A-43B0-ADAF-2B65275726EA.htm) for details when using Intel's MKL.

Comment: Or, use the intrinsic `matmul` function.  Any quibbles about its performance relative to `blas` routines can be ignored when the arrays are only `2 x 5` or so.